# c# WPF Checkbox delete in Listview Grid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, listview, checkbox

how do i delete specific row by select few checkbox and delete them same time?
and also update the XML file
im using sharp serialize

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsyZ2.png)

in the image you cant see how it should look like

Xaml:

```
<ListView  Name="Trilogi" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="201" Margin="265,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="30">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="Chck" Checked="Chck_Checked"  Command="{Binding Check}" Width="50" ></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Veh_Key}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Plate Number" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Veh_Value}"/>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Name="Del" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="523,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

the add is work fine
only the select items in the checkbox 
cs:

```
private void Chck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (var item in Trilogi.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            i   
            veh[item].Veh_Is_Checked = true;
            MessageBox.Show(veh[item].Veh_Key.ToString());
        }
    }


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var item in Trilogi.Items)
        {
            veh.Remove(item as Car);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I can't comment. Don't have enough rep to do. But the answer i will give will assume you use are adding directly to the listview.

I think what you need to do is to create first a List of items when they are checked:

```
List<yourclass> selectedItems = new List<yourclass>();
```

Then on your xaml, you can add as tag the object you are using for binding:

```
<CheckBox Name="Chck" Checked="Chck_Checked"  Command="{Binding Check}" Width="50" tag="{Binding}"></CheckBox>
```

and then what you can do in your check event is to add or remove the items, depending on the value of the checkbox say:

```
private void Chck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    yourclass newVal = (yourclass)chk.Tag;
    if (chk.IsChecked.HasValue && chk.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        selectedItems.Add(newVal);
    }
    else
    {
        selectedItems.Remove(newVal);
    }
}
```

and now on your delete button code, you can loop on the list and remove them. And now you can use the list to then call your code for removing them on your xml as basis on what item to remove

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        foreach (var item in selectedItems)
        {
            Trilogi.Items.Remove(item);
        }
        callMethodToRemoveItemsToXML();
        selectedItems.Clear();
}
```